# Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?

Tags: visual-c++, pip, python-3.7, fast-ai

trying to install fastai using pip but the following error is shown 
i have installed visual studio build tools 2019 but still cant install fastai using pip.

`Installing collected packages: bottleneck, nvidia-ml-py3, fastai
  Running setup.py install for bottleneck ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\icarus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9snii33_\\bottleneck\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\icarus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9snii33_\\bottleneck\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\icarus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bpmup82o\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\icarus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9snii33_\bottleneck\
    Complete output (36 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck
    copying bottleneck\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck
    copying bottleneck\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\benchmark
    copying bottleneck\benchmark\autotimeit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\benchmark
    copying bottleneck\benchmark\bench.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\benchmark
    copying bottleneck\benchmark\bench_detailed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\benchmark
    copying bottleneck\benchmark\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\benchmark
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
    copying bottleneck\slow\move.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
    copying bottleneck\slow\nonreduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
    copying bottleneck\slow\nonreduce_axis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
    copying bottleneck\slow\reduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
    copying bottleneck\slow\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\slow
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\src
    copying bottleneck\src\template.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\src
    copying bottleneck\src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\src
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
    copying bottleneck\tests\input_modifcation_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
    copying bottleneck\tests\list_input_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
    copying bottleneck\tests\move_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
    copying bottleneck\tests\nonreduce_axis_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
    copying bottleneck\tests\nonreduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
    copying bottleneck\tests\reduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
    copying bottleneck\tests\scalar_input_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
    copying bottleneck\tests\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
    copying bottleneck\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck\tests
    copying bottleneck\LICENSE -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\bottleneck
    running build_ext
    building 'bottleneck.reduce' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\icarus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9snii33_\\bottleneck\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\icarus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9snii33_\\bottleneck\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\icarus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bpmup82o\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.`

any kind of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You may not have the right path variable setup. Visual Studio build tools install scripts that you need to run in order to get the right variables in your shell.

This said, on Windows, unless you really want to compile your own version, I would recommend to install it with conda.

First install pytorch using the conda command listed here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

If you have a GPU:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
```

If you use CPU:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

Then install fastai:

```
conda install -c fastai fastai
```

This method works fine on Windows and won't require a compiler.